# How do I combine two rows to create one with null spaces?

Tags: sas

How can I combine two rows to get one row?
[image: example]
![This is the example][1]

Comment: Please show us how you tried to acomplish this, what errors you have, and how you tried to fixed. We are not s resource site. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for DATA UPDATE:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001329151.htm

Example (not sure of your dataset names):

`DATA dset3;
  UPDATE dset1 dset2;
  BY region;
RUN;`

Comment: You use UPDATE on a single source dataset.  Just use the `OBS=0` dataset option on the first reference to the source dataset.  `update dset1(obs=0) dset1;`